# How to combine the use of std::bind with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, stdbind

I need to do something like this more than often:

```
AsyncOperation * pAsyncOperation = new AsyncOperation();
auto bindOperation = std::bind(&AsyncOperation::operator(), std::ref(*pAsyncOperation));
std::thread thread(bindOperation );
thread.join();
```

with `AsyncOperation` being any custom class implementing `operator()` *(also known as function object)*.

Is it possible to indicate to the `std::bind` to use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a `std::ref` ?
This would prevent memory leaks, without my needing to keep a reference on `pAsyncOperation`, and would delete the `AsyncOperation` automatically at the end of the thread, that is the end of this asynchronous task.

EDIT: I don't always have access to std::thread, the thread library can be boost::thread or even any other platform dependent threads. And by consequence, not access to std::async.

My main issue is to have a notion of ownership in the std::bind.

Comment: Have you tried to use `std::shared_ptr`? Looks that compiles without problems: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1e83d9698703711b7ed2ce0d44cf86f2

Comment: What you need to know is that `std::bind` stores bound arguments by value (i.e., as passed), therefore, if you pass an owning pointer by value as one of the parameter, that pointer gets 'copied' into the resulting functor, hence, holding ownership even after the original `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works:

```
struct AsyncOperation {
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "AsyncOperation" << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<AsyncOperation>  pAsyncOperation = std::make_shared<AsyncOperation>();
  auto bindOperation = std::bind(&AsyncOperation::operator(), pAsyncOperation);
  std::thread thread(bindOperation );
  thread.join();
}
```

See: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4bc81bb6c31ba7b2bdeb79ea0e02bb89

Comment: Do you need to use `make_shared`, or will `std::shared_ptr<AsyncOperation> pAsyncOperation( new AsyncOperation() );` do?

Comment: @akaltar you can use both "styles" - but make_shared is better - read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232146/why-is-it-better-to-use-stdmake-instead-of-the-constructor

Answer (score 8):

Do you need `AsyncOperation` to be allocated dynamically? If not, I would do that:

```
auto f = std::async([]{ AsyncOperation()(); });
f.wait();
```

otherwise:

```
std::unique_ptr<AsyncOperation> op(new AsyncOperation);
auto f = std::async([&]{ (*op)(); });
f.wait();
```

You can of course use `std::thread`, but it can provide more problems (i.e. exception handling in other thread). `std::bind` has also its own problems and you will probably better end up with a lambda.

If you really need to pass an ownership to other thread you can also do that:

```
std::unique_ptr<AsyncOperation> op(new AsyncOperation);
auto f = std::async([&](std::unique_ptr<AsyncOperation> op){ (*op)(); }, std::move(op));
f.wait();
```

as lambdas do not support move type captures yet.

I hope that helps.