# Why is it better to use std::make_* instead of the constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

There are some functions in the STL which start with the `make_` prefix like `std::make_pair`, `std::make_shared`, `std::make_unique` etc. Why is it a better practice to use them instead of simply using the constructor ?

```
auto pair2 = std::pair< int, double >( 1, 2.0 );
auto pair3 = std::make_pair( 1, 2.0 );

std::shared_ptr< int > pointer1 = std::shared_ptr< int >( new int( 10 ) );
std::shared_ptr< int > pointer2 = std::make_shared< int >( 10 );
```

- I just see that these functions make the code a little shorter, but is that all ?
- Are there any other advantages ?
- Are these functions safer to use ?

Comment: Not too sure for the new smart pointers, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/purpose-of-stdmake-pair for pairs.

Comment: I believe there are distinct advantages for each, answered in separate existing questions.  `make_pair` [works without the author knowing the types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563) involved.  `make_shared` [provides exception safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648).

Comment: It is better because you type less?

Comment: Now I'm wondering how many `make_` functions are in the STL...

Comment: Related to: [What happens when using make_shared](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24779929/1708801)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aside from the benefit of enabling argument deduction (as already mentioned in other answers), there are also some other benefits.

`std::make_pair<T1, T2>` takes care to *not* simply return `std::pair<T1, T2>`. If you pass in a value using `std::ref`, then the returned pair won't store a `std::reference_wrapper`, it will store a reference.

`std::make_shared` can combine allocations. `shared_ptr` needs some place to hold things like the refcount, weak pointer list, etc. that cannot be stored in the `shared_ptr` directly. These can be combined with the object being created, in one slightly larger block rather than in two separate blocks.

`std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` both make sure that no object gets left behind if exceptions are thrown. If you call a function as `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int), std::shared_ptr<int>(new int))`, then it's possible the compiler first allocates two `int` objects, and then constructs two `shared_ptr<int>` objects. If the *second* allocation fails, and no `shared_ptr<int>` object is set up yet to release the memory on destruction, then you have a memory leak. `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` combine the allocation of `int` and the construction of `std::shared_ptr<int>` in a function call, and the other allocation of `int` and the other construction of `std::shared_ptr<int>` in another function call. Function calls cannot overlap, so if the second allocation fails, there is already a shared pointer that will be destroyed, undoing the first allocation as well.

Comment: `make_` smart pointers also enable the "every `new` is paired with a `delete`" sanity check by eliminating an unpaired `new`.

Comment: Not sure how make_XXX guarantees memory release in your last paragraph. Can you go into more detail.

Comment: @LokiAstari Is this better?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I just had trouble making the logical leap that the whole function `make_XX()` was done before the second function call.

Answer (score 6):

Although it may be subjective, one main touted benefit for this technique is:

> write code against interfaces, not implementations

In essence, function template instantiation performs type deduction based on the arguments you pass, whereas class template instantiation does not. As a consequence, you wouldn't have to pass template arguments as you would when instantiating the class directly.

It should be noted though, that this is not about "saving a few characters", but rather about making your code more general, and avoiding being tied to a concrete type in your function call.

However, this is not always the case, as your `std::make_shared` example showed, there are still cases in which you have to pass the type as a template argument. But, as [Herb Sutter points out](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/), there are several other advantages when it comes to using `std::make_shared`:

1. You should write for clarity and correctness first, and `std::make_shared` achieves both of those (subjective, but I agree)
2. using `std::make_shared` is more efficient, because it allocates your object as well as the `shared_ptr` object in one go, allowing for lower allocation overhead and a likely better cache alignment.

Answer (score 1):

`make_unique` hides from you "raw" pointer, what's usually a good thing - it's less error prone.
`make_shared` may improve memory allocation for `shared_ptr<X>` instances. Normally when you use `shared_ptr<X>` constructor it will allocate memory twice, first for instance of `X` and second for it's internal data (e.g. reference counter). `make_shared` enables optimization - it will create single, internal structure comprising both `X` and reference counter, hence it will perform single memory allocation. And same as before it hides raw pointers.

Comment: but as a drawback, if you keep a weak_ptr<X>, all the memory from your shared_ptr<X> will stay alive instead of only the ref_count block. (but that doesn't matter most of the time)